# Cassia using impersonation and wcf

Tags: wcf, impersonation, terminal-services

I am trying to use [Cassia](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/) with a WCF web service I keep getting "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".  When I try it on a test console application it works fine.  This is the code I am using from a sample I found.  Anyone ever do this?

```
public List<ITerminalServicesSession> getTermminalServerSessions(string serverName)
    {
        ConnectionDetails connection = new ConnectionDetails();
        connection.Domain = "DOMAIN";
        connection.Server = serverName;
        connection.Username = "USER";
        connection.Password = "PASSWORD";
        using (ImpersonationHelper.Impersonate(connection))
        {
            using (var server = GetServer(connection.Server))
            {
                server.Open();
                return server.GetSessions().ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is Cassia? Did you mean Cassini Web server?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/cassia/

Comment: This sounds like a WCF exception rather than a Cassia/Remote Desktop Services one -- can you provide the stack trace?